# Объединения 2 запросов в 1 таблицу

Tags: sql, select, join

Есть 2 запроса и мне необходимо вывести их в одну таблицу.
Код моего запроса:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT id, cnty 
      FROM usr 
      WHERE cnty > 10) a 
JOIN (SELECT id, cntn 
      FROM usr 
      WHERE cntn < 10) b ON b.id = a.id
```

Во-первых, как сделать так, что бы в выводе столбец id в запросе был только один раз, а не 2, как у меня выходит.
Во-вторых, при выводе запроса получается так, что кол-во cntn, попадающих под критерии поиска выходит меньше, чем cnty. То есть, недостающие поля забиваются повторяющимися значениями и их становится больше.
Оригинальная таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получившийся запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы результатом ответа видеть id, cnty, cntn и там, где не попадает под условие, вместо cnty/cntn вставлять NULL.

Comment: 1) Используйте [таблица].[поле] as [значение] т е `table.id as id_firest` 2) Используйте left join или right join вместе с group by.

Comment: *Во-первых, как сделать так, что бы в выводе столбец id в запросе был только один раз, а не 2, как у меня выходит.* Сформулировать дополнительный критерий отбора, который позволит оставить строго одну запись и отбросить остальные - причём как в случае, когда исходному критерию соответствуют несколько записей, так и в случае, когда соответствующих записей нет ни одной. Заодно и "во-вторых" решится. Однако правильнее рассказать, не ЧТО Вы делаете, а ЗАЧЕМ. В чём суть исходных данных, и какая решается задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Case, он решит вашу проблему.

```
select id, case when cnty > 10 then cnty else null end cnty, case cntn < 10 then cntn else null end cntn
from usr
where cnty > 10 or cntn < 10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select u1.id, cnty, cntn
  from usr u1
left outer join usr u2 
  on u1.id = u2.id 
  and u1.cnty > 10 
  and u2.cntn < 10
```